# Change the chartArea background color of gvisAnnotationChart

Tags: r, googlevis

How to change the chartArea background color of gvisAnnotationChart?

I tried this but didn't work (I tried to replicate what I saw in [this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135372/change-border-background-in-google-charts-annotationchart/39138141#39138141)

```
gvisAnnotationChart(
...,
options = list(
    ...,
    chart = list(
      backgroundColor = "#D3D3D3"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: The answer is in the link you provided: It is not implemented in gvisAnnotationChart(). I am not that familiar with googleVis. Maybe there is a workaround?...

Comment: I haven't tested, but could it be because the option is `chartArea.backgroundColor` while you have specified `chart.backgroundColor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using one of the charts in the package demo, with an option for background color designated so you can see how it's documented.

Because the `gvisAnnotationChart` has side panels, chart area, chart, and other designated panel-type areas, all of which could have different backgrounds, you have to be really specific for this type of chart.

```
library(googleVis)
data(Stock)

plot(gvisAnnotationChart(Stock, datevar="Date",
                         numvar="Value", idvar="Device",
                         titlevar="Title", annotationvar="Annotation",
                         options=list(
                           displayAnnotations=TRUE,
                               # make it blue
                           chart = "{chartArea:{backgroundColor:'#003b70'}}",
                           legendPosition='newRow',
                           width=600, height=350)))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Maybe this one too? :-)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71748472/how-to-change-text-color-in-a-voronoitreemap-legend

Comment: I've worked with that question quite a bit. I haven't found anything that's worked so far. There is very little support on that one. There isn't even any widget options built in for options like many other widget-type packages have (i.e., `DT`, `plotly`, etc.).

Comment: I figured that linked question out! Woooo hooo! That one took a while.