# How to change text color in a voronoiTreemap Legend

Tags: r, voronoi

Here is an example. Text color is black by default.

```
library(voronoiTreemap)

data(ExampleGDP)
gdp_json <- vt_export_json(vt_input_from_df(ExampleGDP))
vt_d3(gdp_json, legend=TRUE)
```

Comment: The [function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/voronoiTreemap/versions/0.2.0/topics/vt_d3) shows that you can set `color_label` with a hex color code. Try that.

Comment: @Nico This affects the plot, not the legend (although I do not see it working there either)

Comment: Same, tried it out and it affected nothing. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WOO HOO! I'm pretty happy with myself on this one. I digress.

To set the legend text color change this -> '#b21e29' in the following code:

```
library(voronoiTreemap)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(dplyr)

data(ExampleGDP)
gdp_json <- vt_export_json(vt_input_from_df(ExampleGDP))

# try number 70032536587832
(plt = vt_d3(gdp_json, legend=TRUE) %>% 
    onRender("function(el){
                legends = el.lastChild.lastChild;
                legends.lastChild.setAttribute('style', 'fill: #b21e29;');
             }"))
```

[image]

Comment: If you looked at it before I edited it, I didn't add the libraries initially. I've added them now.

Comment: How did you come up with that double `lastChild`.  Could you lead me towards documentation / background on the subject?

Comment: Several things threw me off course, especially using 'fill' for text. (HTML and CSS use 'color' for text.) What I ended up doing was only coding `console.log(el)`. I went to developer tools -> console and looked at what that collected. It essentially collected how the object is initially created in HTML from JS. I looked for the legend labels. I tried a few different methods (all of which work in HTML, JS, and CSS but didn't necessarily work with `htmlwidgets`) using the console.log. It modifies 4 elements; `htmlwidgets` does the `forEach`. If you want more details, I could mod my answer.